# Defining a schema inside a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on creating a model data base design for a retail store. I'm trying to create a single procedure which will initialize the database schema.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a new schema from inside the procedure. My code is as follows:

```
begin trans

create procedure Retail_Fill
as
    create schema Retail_Test;  
    go
    create table Retail_Test.customer(
        cust_id int,
        cust_name varchar(30),
        cust_phone int,
        cust_add varchar(50),
        constraint pk_customer primary key (cust_id)
    );
```

Here the `create schema` statement works fine by itself. But inside the procedure it gives an error:

> Invaid Syntax!CREATE SCHEMA must be the only statement in the batch

I want to know if it is at all possible to achieve this. If yes then what am I doing wrong or where is the error?

Comment: having GO will be seperate into batches, try eliminating GO

Comment: Why do you want this in a stored procedure? If you do with a SP you need to first create the SP with all the DDL code inside the SP. It would be much easier if you just skipped the stored procedure part and created you table directly.

Comment: Hey Mikael, M a sql_server/sql newbie so trying out its features. I want the procedure to be such that the single procedure should create the entire design.

Comment: You need a single SQL script that creates the entire design. You do not want to put that in a stored procedure.

Comment: @Mikael-> So your trying to say it is not possible to have a schema definition inside a procedure? Ok thanks a bunch Mikael

Comment: It is possible but it is ugly. I will add an answer that works but I'm not suggesting that you do it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CREATE SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx?ppud=4) has to be executed as a separate batch. Batches in SQL Server Management Studio is separated by `GO`. That is not the case in a stored procedure. You can do what you want by using [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) for the statements that needs to be in a batch of its own like `CREATE SCHEMA` or `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

```
create procedure Retail_Fill
as
exec('create schema Retail_Test');

create table Retail_Test.customer(
    cust_id int,
    cust_name varchar(30),
    cust_phone int,
    cust_add varchar(50),
    constraint pk_customer primary key (cust_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mikael Eriksson said above creating DB Schema should be in a single script file or may be you can configure some deployment that will create your schema. So it will be good to avoid creating schema within procedures.

You can have these inside procedure when you have to design the schema on fly for each customer (for example).